# HTML Formatting Question

Tags: html

I am new to HTML programming - have done C++ and C# and such things before so not totally new to the world off programming.  I have taken some code for a timer of the net and i want to modify for my use.  It acceted an numbers for a timer for mins and secs - I changed the max length to 2 and I will do other validation to make sure the values enetered are < 60 for mins and seconds.  However I want to add a third input box for hours which was not on the orignal html code.  I have tried this below however it is not adding it exactly how i want - it is putting it above the mins box so everything looks off centre - is there something i have missed?  Code below (I have commented out my Hrs code which i added.  Many thanks.

```
<TR>  
<TD>
<TABLE style='border-width: 2; border-style: groove; width: 100%; text-align: right'>
<TR><TD>
<!--<TABLE class='form1'>
<TR>
<TD style='text-align: left'>
Hr.<BR>(0-24)
<TD>
<INPUT class='form1' name='_fe_hr_' type='text' value='0' style='width: 30' align='right'>
</TABLE>-->
<TABLE class='form1'>
<TR>
<TD style='text-align: right'>
Min.<BR>(0-59)
<TD>
<INPUT class='form1' name='_fe_min_' type='text' value='0' style='width: 30' maxlength='2'>
</TABLE>
<TD>
<TABLE class='form1'>
<TR>
<TD style='text-align: right'>
Sec.<BR>(0-59)
<TD>
<INPUT class='form1' name='_fe_sec_' type='text' value='0' style='width: 30' maxlength='2'>
</TABLE>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: This uses tables for layout, inputs for output, invalid HTML and invalid CSS. In all seriousness — throw the entire thing away and learn HTML/CSS from [a guide not written in the last millenium](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#Table_of_contents).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the small chance that you aren't trolling..
(*tip: don't use tables for layout next time*)

```
<table style='border-width: 2; border-style: groove; width: 100%; text-align: right'>
    <tr>
        <td style='text-align: right'>
            Hr.<br />(0-24)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class='form1' name='_fe_hr_' type='text' value='0' style='width: 30' align='right'>
        </td>
        <td style='text-align: right'>
            Min.<br />(0-59)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class='form1' name='_fe_min_' type='text' value='0' style='width: 30' maxlength='2'>
        </td>
        <td style='text-align: right'>
            Sec.<br />(0-59)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class='form1' name='_fe_sec_' type='text' value='0' style='width: 30' maxlength='2'>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is trolling?  I think I just got it sorted anyway. Cheers